# error when inserted props in getJSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'll be very grateful who can help me with this line I've this:
i need a props when i load whit json

```
$.getJSON({this.props.archivo}, function(data){
```

and this is the fixed

```
SyntaxError: C:/xampp/htdocs/mip/App.js: Unexpected token (193:17)
  191 |     },
  192 |     componentWillMount: function(){
> 193 |         $.getJSON({this.props.archivo}, function(data){
      |                  ^
```

thanks for you colaboration

Comment: `{this.props.archivo}` <--- so what is this?

Comment: for call the url here 
export var Modulo5 = React.createClass({ 
 render: function(){
  return(
   <Modulo5__ key={1} archivo={"public/datos/file1.json"} ></Modulo5__>
   <Modulo5__ key={2} archivo={"public/datos/file2.json"} ></Modulo5__>
  )
 }
})

Comment: `{this.props.archivo}` --- what does this expression mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.props.archivo` is already a JavaScript object. You only need to wrap it in { } when binding it for rendering.

```
$.getJSON(this.props.archivo, function(data){});
```